# Characterization of pretopological space as a set system

Tags: general-topology

A [set system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets) is a pair $(X, \tau)$ where $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. A [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_open_sets) is a set system where

\begin{align*}
&X \in \tau \\
&(\forall a \in \tau)(\forall b \in \tau)(a \cap b \in \tau) \\
&(\forall S \subseteq \tau)(\mathop{\cup} S \in \tau)
\end{align*}

Is there an analogous characterization of a [pretopological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretopological_space) as a set system, i.e. not in terms of a [preclosure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preclosure_operator) or [neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) system? Does it correspond to any of [these set systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets#Special_types_of_set_families)?